# Does a ball, when thrown into the air, ever experience an instant of rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, acceleration, projectile

Say I walk outside and throw a ball into the air. Obviously it will decelerate as it travels upward due to Earth's gravity, and accelerate as it travels downward for the same reason. But is the ball ever at rest -- say, for even a nanosecond -- between the period of time when it is traveling upward and the period of time when it is travelling downward? Or is the ball either going up or down -- and only up or down -- at any given instance? If so, how does it make the transition from travelling upward to travelling downward?

Comment: Consider the evolution of the velocity vector of the ball throughout its motion and/or see what the kinematic equations tell you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does an object experience motionlessness at the beginning of its descent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96198/)

Comment: You pretty much answered it by your last line. Asking the question "how does it transition from upwards to downwards motion" will make you realize that it of course has to stop in order to turn. Because everything in this world is smooth. Nothing really happens at an instant.

Comment: Note that, while in flight, the velocity of the ball is continuously changing and so, for any velocity between its initial and final velocity, the ball has it for only an instant.  Put another way, if the ball's initial velocity is 10 m/s up and its final is 10 m/s down, does it have a velocity of, say, 1 m/s for more than an instant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ball does have an instant where it is at rest. The ball is constantly accelerating towards the ground, so will slow down to rest while travelling upwards, and then start speeding up downwards. It's as simple as that - a constant acceleration. On Earth this acceleration is ~9.8 ms$^{-2}$ (varying slightly in different locations).

If the ball were to not have an instant where it is at rest, it would have to change velocity instantly, so would require an infinite acceleration -- as $a= \frac{\Delta v}{t}$ and $t = 0$, which is impossible. From this you can see that it would be impossible for it not to have an instant at rest. This graph should help illustrate this, taking up to be positive.

[image]

Comment: That's what I said

Comment: The edits you made have clarified this point now.

Comment: Your units are wrong for acceleration.

Comment: Why use an infinitesimal change in time $t = \Delta t \to 0$ but a finite change in velocity $\Delta v \ne 0$? You should have $g=\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ which remains finite as both $\Delta v \to 0$ and $\Delta t \to 0$. I think your conclusion should be that there is no interval of time of finite duration for which $\Delta v=0$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to this is to consider a theorem in analysis known as the intermediate value theorem: this states, in its simplest form, that, given a function $f$ which is continuous on some interval $[a, b]\subset \mathbb{R}$, then, if $f(a) \le f(b)$, for any $y \in [f(a), f(b)]$ there is an $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x) = y$, and equivalently if $f(a) \ge f(b)$.

Well, upward velocity in this case is continuous as a function of time, and at the start of the trajectory it is positive and at the end it is negative: therefore, by the intermediate value theorem there must be some point in the trajectory where it is zero.

This may seem like an absurdly mathematical way of looking at the problem: physical intuition can tell you the same thing.  But actually I think it's useful to try and apply analysis in these simple cases because it has the great property that it's made of theorems with clear assumptions ('velocity is a continuous function if time’) which then spit out unambiguous answers: this can be extremely useful in cases where physical intuition may be less useful, or unavailable.

Comment: while it is correct to use this result the drawback of this approach is that it does not identify the number of points which satisfy the intermediate value, i.e. in this case it guarantees *at least* one $t$ where $v=0$ without indicating there is only a *single* $t$ for which this is true.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would supplement it by pointing out two things. (1) The intermediate value theorem is really just a thinly veiled statement of the completeness property of the real number system. (2) There is no way, even in principle, to experimentally test whether actual spacetime has the completeness property.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You could do that by showing that $v(t)$ is monotonically decreasing, hence it is a one to one for appropriate intervals, hence it has an inverse on those intervals & thus there can be exactly one point.  But really what I was trying to get at is that you can crank up all this formal mechanism to supplement your intuition, or replace it if it has failed: it took me a long time to understand that.

Comment: @BenCrowell I agree.  However (see other comment) what I was really trying to do was to show that you can crank up bits of maths to help supplement physical intuition, and this can help (usually in more complicated situations than this!).

Answer (score 1):

The vertical velocity is $0$ - and thus the ball is instantaneously at rest (in the vertical direction) - at the very moment the ball reaches its maximum height.

One understands this by contradiction: if the ball still had vertical speed at that time, it would continue going up and thus would not have reached maximum height.

Because the acceleration is constant (if the only force is gravity) the velocity (initially positive) decreases in time as
$$
v(t)=v_0-gt
$$
showing that $0$-velocity is reached after $t=v_0/g$.